# WebAssembly use i64 as Branch Condition

Tags: webassembly

I wanted to know what the best way to convert an i64 into an i32 so that I can use it as a condition to a `br_if`. My current solution is to use `i64.popcnt` and `i32.wrap_i64` but I feel like there should be a better solution.

```
;; ... something that gives i64 ...
i64.popcnt
i32.wrap_i64 ;; optimize?
if
    ;; ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe `i64.eqz` + `i32.eqz` would be more performant?